# Show files inside container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-container

When I run `docker container run -it <image_id>` for any Dockerfile I can see in the terminal the files inside the container.

I tried to run it on a specific Dockerfile, which seems to be built successfully, I am getting the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket 
        "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
```

What can be the reason it fails on specific Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker run <image_id>`, the default `ENTRYPOINT` is executed.

The execution command depends on the container and on how it's defined in the `Dockerfile`.

You can override it using the [`--entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) flag. For example:

```
docker run --entrypoint "/bin/ls /dir" <image>
```